# no more data read from socket error with triggers

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I have created one trigger that calls one procedure, using oracle sql developper. Here is the code for trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER noteTrigger
  BEFORE
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE OF valoare OR
    DELETE
  ON note
BEGIN
  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Inserting');
      updateBursa();
    WHEN UPDATING('valoare') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating valoare');
      updateBursa();
    WHEN DELETING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Deleting');
      updateBursa();
  END CASE;
END;
/
```

Now, the procedure is written here :

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateBursa IS
v_countBursieri NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  UPDATE STUDENTI SET bursa = null;
  FOR v_i IN (SELECT nr_matricol from studenti natural join note group by nr_matricol having avg(valoare) = 
          (select max(avg(valoare)) from studenti natural join note group by nr_matricol)) LOOP
          v_countBursieri := v_countBursieri + 1;
  END LOOP;
  FOR v_i IN (SELECT nr_matricol from studenti natural join note group by nr_matricol having avg(valoare) = 
          (select max(avg(valoare)) from studenti natural join note group by nr_matricol)) LOOP

          UPDATE STUDENTI SET bursa = 1000/v_countBursieri where nr_matricol = v_i.nr_matricol;
  END LOOP; 

END;
/
```

And when I try to modify note table by this :

```
INSERT INTO note VALUES ('111', '25',  5, TO_DATE('20/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
```

I get error :

```
Error report -
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kqlidchg0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$) violated
00603. 00000 -  "ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error"
*Cause:    An Oracle server session was in an unrecoverable state.
*Action:   Log in to Oracle again so a new server session will be created
           automatically.  Examine the session trace file for more
           information.
Error report -
SQL Error: No more data to read from socket
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Error can happen with PL/SQL and came up with `ORA-600 [kqlidchg0]`,`ORA-00001` and/or `ORA-01578` see MOS Doc ID 17210525.8.

For 12.1 and 11.2 install latest Patch (April 2016)

`ORA-600 [kqlidchg0]` with PL/SQL

`ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_PLSCOPE_SIG_IDENTIFIER$) violated`

Try:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS = 'IDENTIFIERS:NONE';
```